# Bind/tie scroll position of two LongListSelectors

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows Phone app, I've got two [`LongListSelectors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) side-by-side on a page. I would like to make it so that when the user scrolls one of them, the other one scrolls the same amount.

The two `LongListSelectors` have ItemTemplates that will always be of identical heights. You can kind of think of this as mimicking frozen columns in Excel (the left `LongListSelector` only scrolls vertically, the right one scrolls horizontally and vertically.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this? I'm willing to do it in code-behind or whatever if it can't be done with binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by hooking into the ViewportControl of the LongListSelector. When the viewport of one LLS changes, change the Viewport of the other LLS. I'm guessing you only need two LLS, so a single DependencyProperty should do the trick. I wrote up [a blog](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/01/16/Synching-the-scroll-position-of-two-LongListSelectors.aspx) with all of the details on how to accomplish this.

The short of it is the need for a DependencyProperty

```
public double ScrollPosition
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ViewPortProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ViewPortProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewPortProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ScrollPosition", 
    typeof(double), 
    typeof(MyLongListSelector), 
    new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnViewPortChanged));
```

And set the property when the Viewport changes.

```
private void OnViewportChanged(object sender, ViewportChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ScrollPosition = _viewport.Viewport.Top;
}
```

Then bind the property to each LLS in your xaml

```
<dataBoundApp1:MyLongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                    ScrollPosition="{Binding ScrollPosition, ElementName=MainLongListSelector2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<dataBoundApp1:MyLongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Column="1" 
                                    ScrollPosition="{Binding ScrollPosition, ElementName=MainLongListSelector, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Great implementation!

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot - Thanks so much for this implementation. I used it and got it working about 95% of the way. It is probably good enough but I have one follow up - is there any way to make the "bounce" and "stretch" sync between them? If you swipe all the way to the top of one, it will go a little further down than it should, but the other one will not. You can see it in your Youtube clip right at the end. That isn't the biggest issue in the world, but since your answer was so spot on I figured I'd see if you could solve that too.

Comment: Give a mouse a cookie, huh? Geez! (just kidding). I'll see if there is a way to solve that, maybe over the weekend.

Comment: LOL. No worries if its not something you've got on the top of your head or that you're not interested in looking into.

Answer (score 3):

While I've never developed for Windows Phone I'm very familiar with XAML from WPF and have had similiar problems where I've needed to sync the width of bars across several bar charts. My proposed solution uses Dependency Properties to allow you to bind your ListSelectors in XAML like with the `SharedSizeGroup` in Grids. If you're not familiar with Dependency Properties start by looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since I don't have acces to the requiered assemblies for Windows Phone this hasn't been tested but it does work in very similiar scenarios.

```
public class SyncedLongListSelector : LongListSelector
{
    private ScrollBar scrollBar;

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<SyncedLongListSelector>> Groupings = new Dictionary<string, List<SyncedLongListSelector>>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GroupName", typeof(string), typeof(SyncedLongListSelector), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string GroupName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(GroupNameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        scrollBar = GetTemplateChild("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar; // See my comments

        if (scrollBar != null)
            scrollBar.Scroll += OnScroll;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void UpdateScrolPosition(double scrollBarValue)
    {
        scrollBar.Value = scrollBarValue;
    }

    private void OnScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var otherList in Groupings[GroupName].Where(l => !Equals(l, this)))
            otherList.UpdateScrolPosition(scrollBar.Value);
    }
}
```

`scrollBar = GetTemplateChild("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;` I found the string to use in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you provided.

You might need to add something if setting `scrollBar.Value` raises the `OnScroll`-event so you don't get a stack overflow :)

Also adding the controls to the `Grouping`-dictionary is left as an execise to the reader, it should be quite easy. If making your own controls is new to you try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) resource for starters.

To use your ready control simply add it in XAML like so: `<yourNamespace:SyncedLongListSelector GroupName="MySyncedGroup" />`

Comment: Thanks @Zache - I will give this route a shot tonight and let you know my results. Much appreciated!

Comment: wish I could give you part of the bounty, as your solution was very close to being what I needed, Shawn's was just a little more complete. Gave you an upvote for sure though! Thanks again!